# MacBook tries to connect to colleague's Apple Watch

Tags: macos, bluetooth, apple-watch

My colleague's Apple Watch keeps asking if he wants to accept pairing with my MacBook Pro. I have never had his Apple Watch connected to my MacBook (or tried to do so...), but I did have his iPhone connected through a USB cable, to launch an iOS app on it (through Xcode).

I cannot see any sign of the Apple Watch on my MacBook. I have no idea why it tries to connect with his Apple Watch. I do not own an Apple Watch.

How do I stop this? It is quite annoying for my colleague.

Comment: If your colleague declines the pairing, do the requests still continue?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, they come randomly and he declines them every time.

Comment: If your colleague _accepts_ the pairing, do the requests continue?

Comment: I don't want to do that and I don't see how that would solve the problem.